# Sorting dates which are not in right format

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, date, momentjs

I am getting input from the excel sheet and the dates are not in proper ISO format which can be operated on i.e the column looks something like below, I am trying to sort it using converting it to proper date using javascript date and moment however I am not getting proper output I can use a second opinion on this matter.

- Input `["28/02/23","31/12/21","31/05/21","30/09/23","31/10/22","30/09/21","30/06/23","31/05/22","30/04/21","31/07/21","30/06/21","28/02/22","31/12/22","30/06/22","31/08/21","30/04/22","31/10/20","31/08/22","31/07/22","31/05/23","31/01/23","30/04/23","30/09/22","28/02/21","30/11/20","30/11/21","31/01/21","31/03/23","31/01/22","31/07/23","31/12/20","31/03/21","31/08/23","30/11/22","31/10/21","31/03/22","30/09/20"]`
- method I wrote

  ```
  dateCompare = (d1, d2) => {
    let d1Component = d1.toString().split('/')
      , d2Component = d2.toString().split('/')
      , rD1 = new Date(parseInt(20 + d1Component[2]), d1Component[1] - 1, d1Component[0])
      , rD2 = new Date(parseInt(20 + d2Component[2]), d2Component[1] - 1, d2Component[0])
    return moment(rD1).isAfter(moment(rD2))
  }
  ```
- The output I am getting from above method is  `["30/09/35", "28/02/23", "31/05/21", "31/12/21", "31/10/22", "30/09/21", "30/09/20", "31/05/22", "30/04/21", "31/07/21", "30/06/21", "28/02/22", "31/12/22", "30/06/22", "31/08/21", "30/04/22", "31/10/20", "31/08/22", "31/07/22", "31/03/22", "31/01/23", "31/10/21", "30/09/22", "28/02/21", "30/11/20", "30/11/21", "31/01/21", "30/11/22", "31/01/22", "31/03/21", "31/12/20", "31/01/37", "31/07/23", "31/03/23", "30/04/23", "31/05/23", "30/06/23", "30/04/37", "31/10/23", "31/08/23", "30/09/23", "30/06/37", "29/02/24", "30/11/23", "31/12/23", "31/01/24", "31/08/37", "31/07/24", "31/03/24", "30/04/24", "31/05/24", "30/06/24", "30/11/37", "31/01/25", "31/08/24", "30/09/24", "31/10/24", "30/11/24", "31/12/24", "31/03/38", "31/08/25", "28/02/25", "31/03/25", "30/04/25"]` which I believe is not at all sorted in any ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparison function should return a negative number for less than, a positive number for greater than, and `0` for equal to, not `true`/`false`. Also, since you're already using `moment`, use it to parse the dates as well:

```js
function dateCompare(d1, d2) {
    const d1Parsed = moment(d1, "DD/MM/YY");
    const d2Parsed = moment(d2, "DD/MM/YY");
    if (d1Parsed.isBefore(d2Parsed)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (d1Parsed.isSame(d2Parsed)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, take the difference of their timestamps (if `d1Parsed` is before `d2Parsed` then its timestamp will be less, so the resulting subtraction will be negative, if they're equal it'll be 0, and if it's greater it'll be positive, doing the same thing as the previous code):

```js
function dateCompare(d1, d2) {
    const d1Parsed = moment(d1, "DD/MM/YY");
    const d2Parsed = moment(d2, "DD/MM/YY");
    return d1Parsed.valueOf() - d2Parsed.valueOf();
}
```

Comment: Wonderful precise, concise and accurate. I did not think it needs -1, 0 or 1. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jeet I've edited in a clarification into my answer that makes it even shorter.

Comment: Somewhat shorter as `return moment(d1, "DD/MM/YY") - moment(d2, "DD/MM/YY");` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use map and convert the dates, than sort them.

```js
const dates = ["28/02/23", "31/12/21", "31/05/21", "30/09/23", "31/10/22", "30/09/21", "30/06/23", "31/05/22", "30/04/21", "31/07/21", "30/06/21", "28/02/22", "31/12/22", "30/06/22", "31/08/21", "30/04/22", "31/10/20", "31/08/22", "31/07/22", "31/05/23", "31/01/23", "30/04/23", "30/09/22", "28/02/21", "30/11/20", "30/11/21", "31/01/21", "31/03/23", "31/01/22", "31/07/23", "31/12/20", "31/03/21", "31/08/23", "30/11/22", "31/10/21", "31/03/22", "30/09/20"];

const convertedDates = dates.map(d => {
  var day = d.split("/")[0];
  var month = d.split("/")[1];
  var year = d.split("/")[2];

  return "20" + year + '-' + ("0" + month).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + day).slice(-2);
})
.sort();
;

console.log(convertedDates);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using a third party library, you could convert the custorm date to an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant date string and sort with
[`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
const
    getISO = string => string.replace(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)/, '20$3-$2-$1'),
    data = ["28/02/23", "31/12/21", "31/05/21", "30/09/23", "31/10/22", "30/09/21", "30/06/23", "31/05/22", "30/04/21", "31/07/21", "30/06/21", "28/02/22", "31/12/22", "30/06/22", "31/08/21", "30/04/22", "31/10/20", "31/08/22", "31/07/22", "31/05/23", "31/01/23", "30/04/23", "30/09/22", "28/02/21", "30/11/20", "30/11/21", "31/01/21", "31/03/23", "31/01/22", "31/07/23", "31/12/20", "31/03/21", "31/08/23", "30/11/22", "31/10/21", "31/03/22", "30/09/20"];

data.sort((a, b) => getISO(a).localeCompare(getISO(b)));

console.log(data);
```